# Ruby array of hashes, compare 2 keys and sum another key/value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

In Ruby I have the following array of hashes:

```
[
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'},
  {:qty => 4, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'}
]
```

What I need to be able to do is compare the elements by the `:unit` and `:type` and then sum the `:qty` when they are the same.  The resulting Array should look like follows:

```
[
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'},
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'}
]
```

If the array has multiple hashes where the `:qty` is `nil` and the `:unit` is empty (`""`), then it would only return one of those.  So to extend the above example, this:

```
[
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => nil, :unit => '', :type => 'Foo'},
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'},
  {:qty => 4, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => nil, :unit => '', :type => 'Foo'}
]
```

would become this:

```
[
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'},
  {:qty => nil, :unit => '', :type => 'Foo'},
  {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'},
  {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'}
]
```

EDIT: Sorry, made a mistake in the second example... it shouldn't have the o.

Comment: How are you going to give bonus points?

Comment: Your second example doesn’t make sense, why is there no hash with unit `'o'` in the result?

Comment: You're right, just edited it.

Comment: Are you expecting there are lots of such data and work to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) with the keys you want, then [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) the `qty`s in each value into a single hash, or instead using `nil` if they are all `nil`:

```
properties.group_by do |property|
  property.values_at :type, :unit
end.map do |(type, unit), properties|
  quantities = properties.map { |p| p[:qty] }
  qty = quantities.all? ? quantities.reduce(:+) : nil
  { type: type, unit: unit, qty: qty }
end

#=> [{:type=>"mass", :unit=>"oz", :qty=>5},
#    {:type=>"Foo", :unit=>"", :qty=>nil},
#    {:type=>"vol", :unit=>"oz", :qty=>5},
#    {:type=>"mass", :unit=>"lbs", :qty=>1}]
```

Where `properties` is your second sample input data.

Comment: `reduce(:+)` => `sum(0)` (if you're using activesupport)

Comment: @MarianTheisen Ruby doesn't have a `sum` method.

Comment: @MarianTheisen Ruby has no `sum` method, it only exists in ActiveSupport.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall But you missed one entry... that *Bonus* matter.. :) :)

Comment: @Babai Not really, the OP’s example output does not match their criteria for how it should be generated. See my comment on the question. My answer will work just fine for *any* “and” condition between the type and unit.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want [`enumberable.group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

This should get you started

```
items.group_by { |item| item.values_at(:unit, :type) }
```

Output

```
{
  ["oz", "mass"]=> [
    {:qty=>1, :unit=>"oz", :type=>"mass"},
    {:qty=>4, :unit=>"oz", :type=>"mass"}
  ],
  ["oz", "vol"]=>[
    {:qty=>5, :unit=>"oz", :type=>"vol"}
  ],
  ["lbs", "mass"]=>[
    {:qty=>1, :unit=>"lbs", :type=>"mass"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ar = [{:qty => 1, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'}, {:qty => nil, :unit => '', :type => 'Foo'}, 
      {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'}, 
      {:qty => 4, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'}, {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'}, 
      {:qty => nil, :unit => 'o', :type => 'Foo'}]

result = ar.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e,hsh|
    if hsh.has_key?({:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]})
        hsh[{:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]}] += e[:qty]
    else
        hsh[{:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]}] = e[:qty]
    end
end

result.map{|k,v| k[:qty] = v;k }.delete_if{|h| h[:qty].nil? and !h[:unit].empty? }
# => [{:unit=>"oz", :type=>"mass", :qty=>5},
#     {:unit=>"", :type=>"Foo", :qty=>nil},
#     {:unit=>"oz", :type=>"vol", :qty=>5},
#     {:unit=>"lbs", :type=>"mass", :qty=>1}]
```

---

Taking **@Andrew Marshall** under consideration

```
ar = [{:qty => 1, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'}, {:qty => nil, :unit => '', :type => 'Foo'}, 
      {:qty => 5, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'vol'}, 
      {:qty => 4, :unit => 'oz', :type => 'mass'}, {:qty => 1, :unit => 'lbs', :type => 'mass'}, 
      {:qty => nil, :unit => 'o', :type => 'Foo'}]

result = ar.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e,hsh|
    if hsh.has_key?({:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]})
        hsh[{:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]}] += e[:qty]
    else
        hsh[{:unit => e[:unit], :type => e[:type]}] = e[:qty]
    end
end

result.map{|k,v| k[:qty] = v;k }.delete_if{|h| h[:qty].nil? and h[:unit].empty? }
# => [{:unit=>"oz", :type=>"mass", :qty=>5},
#     {:unit=>"oz", :type=>"vol", :qty=>5},
#     {:unit=>"lbs", :type=>"mass", :qty=>1},
#     {:unit=>"o", :type=>"Foo", :qty=>nil}]
```

Comment: Yes it is.. See the line *If the array has multiple hashes where the :qty is nil AND the unit is empty (""), then it would only return one of those.*.

Comment: No, I mean that the result you have at the end of your answer is not what your code actually returns. And is not the format desired by the OP.

Comment: I see what I did. I was looking at the value of `result`. Futher, you did not follow the OP’s criteria. You delete the element if `:unit` is *not* empty.